# Code runs in local IDE but online. Somehow going outside vector limit

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

Runtime Error Message:

Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:9

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    int firstMissingPositive(vector<int>& nums) {
        int sp, lp, sm;
        sp = nums[0];
        lp = nums[0];
        sm = nums[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++){

            if(nums[i]<sp && nums[i]>0)
            {
                if(sp - nums[i]>1){
                    sm = nums[i] + 1;
                }
                sp = nums[i];
            }
            if(nums[i] > lp)
            {
                lp = nums[i];
            }
            if( (nums[i-1] > 0) && ( (nums[i] - nums[i-1]) > 1 ) )
            {
                sm = nums[i] + 1;
            }
            if(nums[i]-nums[i-1]<-1)
            {
                if ( (nums[i]<= 0)){
                    if (sp>=1){
                     sm = 1;   
                    }
                }
                else{
                    sm = nums[i] + 1;
                }
            }

        }
        if(sm==lp || sm==sp || sm==nums[0]){
            sm = lp + 1;
        }
        if(sp>1){
            sm = 1;
        }
        return sm;
        
    }
};

 int main()
 {
     vector<int> g1{3, 4, -1, 1};

     Solution m;
     cout << m.firstMissingPositive(g1);
 }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause a runtime error assuming that the vector has at least one element and I'm unable to reproduce the error. Please show a [mre].

Comment: I guess their test uses an empty vector. @BessieTheCow hinted to that

Comment: Why did you bother making a class just to hold one function?

Comment: @BessieTheCow this code throws an error when used here: https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/description/

Comment: @3Dave I used the code here https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/description/

Comment: @ParamChauhan BessieTheCow already hinted at the issue. The tests do not meet the assumptions in your solution.

Comment: @ParamChauhan Ah. Usual Leetcode BS. You're solution is failing because their tests are passing in a vector that doesn't have at least one element. Go fix it. The error is likely in the line `if(sm==lp || sm==sp || sm==nums[0]){`. Since an empty `nums` wouldn't have a `nums[0]`... I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

Comment: @3Dave Oops, sorry a beginner here. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @ParamChauhan Beginners are welcome, and we've all been there. No need to apologize. We all started somewhere.